# How may records can a Cursor can hold

Tags: cursor, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using **SQL Server 2008**.

I want to select a long list of records and add it to a cursor and iterate through those records to accomplish some task. But I do not know the limitations of this cursor.

**Q:**
Is there a maximum number of records that the cursor can hold. Or is it unlimited and handled internally using some kind of paging technique to handle the records dynamically.

**Code:**

```
 DECLARE cursor CURSOR FOR  
 SELECT C1 
 FROM T1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question of mine is not answered for a while now. This is what I have understood. I used cursor to store 12000 records and iterated through it. I worked just fine. So I know for now for less than 12000 records courser works fine.

If you found more on this, please leave a comment of a best answer. I will not hesitate to change that to my correct answer.